# Opencv: how to compute a 3d histogram?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

i'm new to OpenCV and i'm going to write the following code in order to compute a quantized and weighted histogram of an rgb image.

M is a map of weights. This is a Mat object with the same dimensions of the input image.
First of all i put all (double) values in the range [1,8]. Then, for each triple of rgb values (1,1,1), (1,1,2), .... (8,8,8) i want to sum the value of the corresponding weight. So that when i find the triple (1,2,1) i know that it corresponds to the bin 9 (i.e. the 9-th bin). So i try to sum the value of M(x,y) to the current bin accumulator H but it doesn't work!

NB: In my matlab code i do that using accumarray
However, there is something wrong when i do

```
H.at<uchar>(idx,1) = H.at<uchar>(idx,1) + M.at<double>(Point(x, y));
```

if i run M.type() it returns the value 3

```
Mat H = Mat::zeros(1,512,CV_8UC1);

    for (int y = 0; y < R.rows; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < R.cols; ++x) {

            intensity = R.at<double>(Point(x, y));
            p = intensity[0];
            r = 1 + floor(p * 7.9999);
            cout << "R index = " << r << endl << endl;


            intensity = G.at<double>(Point(x, y));
            p = intensity[0];
            g = 1 + floor(p * 7.9999);
            cout << "G index = " << g << endl << endl;


            intensity = B.at<double>(Point(x, y));
            p = intensity[0];
            b = 1 + floor(p * 7.9999);
            cout << "B index = " << b << endl << endl;

            C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = r;
            C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = g;
            C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2] = b;

            //idx = 1 +((r-1)*64  +  (g-1)*8  +  (b-1)*1 )
            //Here i don't sum 1 because in C the indices starts from 0
            idx =  (r - 1) * 64 + (g - 1) * 8 + (b - 1) * 1;

            H.at<uchar>(idx,1) = H.at<uchar>(idx,1) + M.at<double>(Point(x, y));
            cout << endl << idx;

        }
    }
```

**Edit**
Ok, let me say some changes after your suggestions, these are the initializations of C and H

```
cv::Mat C(doubleRed.rows, doubleRed.cols, CV_8UC3);
Mat H = Mat::zeros(1, 512, CV_16UC1);
```

I solved an error occurred in

```
C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = r;
C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = g;
C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2] = b;
```

inverting the x and the y it wokrs... but i wish understand the why i have to do that.... However the code still crashes when i try to use the function at() of H:

```
H.at<uchar>(idx, 1) = H.at<uchar>(idx, 1) + M.at<double>(Point(x, y));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I've noticed that might help:

You declare `H` as follows:

```
Mat H = Mat::zeros(1,512,CV_8UC1);
```

Then you access it like so:

```
H.at<uchar>(idx,1) = ...
```

So you're creating a matrix with `1 row` and `512 columns` and then accessing `row idx` and `column 1`. You need to swap the indices in your `at`:

```
H.at<uchar>(1,idx) = ...
```

**Edit**:
The reason the indices seem backwards is that `at()` orders the arguments like:

```
H.at<uchar>(row,column) ... or
H.at<uchar>(y, x) ...
```

This is the opposite of `Point`, which orders the arguments like:

```
Point2f P(column, row); or
Point2f P(x, y);
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at

Also, I don't know how many items you plan to have in each bin, but unless it's fewer than 256, `CV_8UC1` is too small.

Finally, images in OpenCV are usually in BGR order, so your

```
        C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = r;
        C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = g;
        C.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2] = b;
```

is probably backwards. For speed you might also want to call `at` only once and store the value in a `Vec3b` before accessing the individual elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've just to sum up the values in M which have the same combination of r,g,b.
Actually, i've planned to use C as a map of indices and not as an image so the order of r g and b in this case doesn't care.. 
Which kind of data type you suggest for H? why not a simple int H[512] ?

Comment: @user2614596 The type you use depends on how large the value is that you will store in `H`. You are currently using `CV_8UC1`, which is an 8-bit unsigned integer that will only store values from `[0..255]`. If you expect values outside this range you should use `CV_16UC1` or `CV_32SC1` (there are no `CV_32U` types).

Comment: This still not works... i've edited the question to add details, but the access to H is not clear. The values of M are "big" unsigned integers.

Comment: @user2614596 I've added an update. You still appear to be using the incorrect argument ordering to access `H`.

Comment: Yes.. Sorry you re right... I ve solved using CV_16UC1 in the H declaration and <unsigned short> to access the H values